# AltGr makes Ctrl stuck on Linux Mint running in Virtual Box under Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I have Windows 8.1 and have installed VirtualBox 4.3.14 to run Linux Mint 17 Xfce in it.

Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in the virtual Linux Mint makes it think that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys is pressed down until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again to "reset" it.

So for example when I am in a text editor and I press (and release) <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>c</kbd> acts as if I had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, using the mouse wheel zooms in or out instead of scrolling and so on...

Please note that changing the VirtualBox's Host key (which is by coincidence set on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> by default) doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I have managed to solve the problem while typing in the question. :)

What helped me was to go to Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager, navigate to File -> Preferences -> Input and disable "Auto capture keyboard" there.